# unintended redirect with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a simple react app with a react router set up like this. It sits at my app's root (`/`)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

import Main from "./components/main";
import Index from "./components/polls/index";
import New from "./components/polls/new";
import Show from "./components/polls/show";
import PollAdmin from "./components/polls/poll_admin"

render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
      // more components here, removed for brevity
    </Route>

  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

When the user logs in (not part of the router), they are redirected back to `/`. 
Once they do so, the `Index` component responds (see below). 
The browser then visits `/api/polls`, which is not what's intended. 
`/api/polls` is an api end point to fetch data to display.
I confirmed this by removing the `componentDidMount` function. With that function gone, the browser does not visit /api/polls

Why is the browser visiting `/api/polls` instead of making an asynchronous request? How do I properly redirect back to `/`?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';

class Index extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      polls: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;

      axios('/api/polls')
        .then(function(result){
          _this.setState({
            polls: result.data.polls
          })
        })
        .catch(function(err){
        })

  }

  ...
  }

}

export default Index;
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? Where does redirect actually happens? What LOC causes it?

Answer (score 0):

After a little more poking around I solved the problem. When first visiting `/` the component `Index` makes an async request to `/api/polls`. Then the user logs in via Twitter. Here are the relevant routes:

```
router.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));
router.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/');
});
```

The problem was that `req.session.returnTo` stored `/api/polls` as the last "visited" url. After logging in the browser redirects to `/api/polls` rendering some ugly json on the page. For my purposes, this was an easy fix. I just changed the route to:

```
router.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Users are always redirected back to `/` which is exactly what I want. I'm not certain what to do if you want to redirect back to the user's last page.